# How clear two RichTextBox using CheckedListBox and button

Tags: c#, button, richtextbox, checkedlistbox

can anybody say me, how can I clear content inside RichTextBox using one button where: CheckedListBox - select which of rtb will be cleared?

[image: How to clear rtb using button and CheckedListBox]

I have problem with CheckedListBox - It works for one select position, but not for checked/marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    string str = (string)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
                    if(str ==  "rtb1")
                    {
                      richTextBox1.Clear();
                      richTextBox1.Focus();
                    }
                     if(str ==  "rtb2")
                    {
                       richTextBox2.Clear();
                       richTextBox2.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but it didn't all works. When I checked 2 position from CheckedListBox (so I marked rtb1 and rtb2) and click button, it only clear text from rtb2. I'm looking for way "one click, 2 clear".

Comment: @TomekeM I modified it please check

Comment: thank You, that's what I need :) greetings from Poland.

Comment: @TomekeM Greetings from SriLanka :)